# Location not update during phone call

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, location, cllocationmanager

I configured my app for receiving location update in the background, and everything works fine except one thing - location not update during phone call (when used only 3G, WI-FI is off). 
Can someone explain me why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make a call and access data at the same time then you may see this type of problem, it totally depends upon on the mobile phone that you are using. To access data during calls, your phone should support dual band technology. When making a call you are already using some bandwidth. This same bandwidth is used for accessing internet by your phone if it does not support dual band channels then you will face this type of problems. Also, sometimes the network providers themselves do not allow you to make a call and access internet at the same time. Try with other mobile network or other mobile phone. For confirming whether you are getting data during the call or not, try to open some other apps like "youtube" during the call and check whether you are able to view the app. If you are able to view the app then you are doing something wrong with your location based services code. Ask another question by posting your code for fetching the location, so that We can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know Apple provides information about supporting dual band technology in the specifications for their devices?

Answer (score 0):

> you'll go to setting --  privacy -- location on -- your app -- set always or while using app

Comment: I already use location access - "Always". As I wrote above problem only during phone call, if I just move app in the background all works fine.